# Find optimal BezierFunction

Tags: mathematical-optimization, splines

For a given set of points (examplary quadrant)

```
n = 5; (* number of inner points*)
p = Table[{Cos[φ], Sin[φ]}, {φ, Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}, n], {Pi/2}]}];
```

I want to calculate the optimal controlpoint `{kx,ky}` of a 3point  bezier function(using `BezierFunction`).

An optimal controlpoint seems to exist for this problem:

```
Manipulate[
  Show[{
    ParametricPlot[
      BezierFunction[{p[[1]], {kx, ky }, p[[-1]]}][u] // Evaluate, {u, 0, 1}],
    ListPlot[p],
    Graphics[{Red, Point[{kx, ky}],Text["{kx,ky}", {kx, ky}, {0, -1}]}]}], 
  {{kx, .7}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{ky, .7}, 0, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

I tried

some variable bezier parameters(to be optimized too):

```
ui = Table[u[i], {i, 2, Length[p] - 1}];
```

general bezier curve with variable control point :

```
bez[k_ ] := BezierFunction[k]
```

**But optimization gives several errors**

```
NMinimize[Sum[Norm[ bez[{p[[1]], {kx, ky}, p[[-1]]}][u[i]] - p[[i]]], 
            {i, 2, Length[p] - 1}], 
  Join[{kx, ky}, ui] ] 
(*BezierFunction::invcpts: {{1,0},{kx,ky},{0,1}} should be a rectangular array of 
  machine-sized real numbers of any depth, 
  whose dimensions are greater than 1., ...*)
```

The argument of `bez[...]` is rectangular, though I don't understand the message.

**What's wrong with my attempt?** Thanks!

**=> SOLUTION:  Thanks a lot @SjoerdSmid**

With userdefined bezier function `bezCurve`

```
bezCurve[{pt : {_, _}}] := pt &;
bezCurve[ctrlPts_?MatrixQ] := bezCurve[ctrlPts] = With[{
b1 = bezCurve[Most[ctrlPts]],b2 = bezCurve[Rest[ctrlPts]]}
, (1 - #)*b1[#] + #*b2[#] &];
bezCurve[ctrlPts_?MatrixQ, t_] := Simplify[bezCurve[ctrlPts][t]];
```

the optimization is done in ~7seconds

```
opt = NMinimize[{Sum[Norm[bezCurve[{p[[1]], {kx, ky}, p[[-1]]}][u[i]] - p[[i]]], 
                   {i, 2,Length[p] - 1}], 
                 Join[{0}, ui, {1}] /. List -> Less, 0 <= kx <= 1 , 0 <= ky <= 1}, 
        Join[{kx, ky}, ui ]]
(*{1.22189, {kx -> 0.899875, ky -> 0.999976, 
             u[2] -> 0.152739, u[3] -> 0.152739, 
             u[4] -> 0.152739, u[5] -> 0.152739,u[6] -> 0.244299}}*)
```

Comment: Definition of `bez` is wrong. Just test it with any valid argument.

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, I tried `Show[{ParametricPlot[
   bez[{p[[1]], {0.75, 0.75 }, p[[-1]]}][u], {u, 0, 1}], ListPlot[p]}] ` and it looks fine!

Comment: Your `bez` is polluted. Check `DownValues@bez`, then `Clear@bez` and retry.

Comment: That means the conditional argument check is wrong? If I define `Clear[bez];
bez[k_] := BezierFunction[k]` the function can be plotted  but the NMinimze-error is still present.

Comment: Yes, it's wrong, try `NumericQ /@ {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}`. Then, execute `Sum[Norm[ bez[{p[[1]], {kx, ky}, p[[-1]]}][u[i]] - p[[i]]], {i, 2, Length[p] - 1}]` outside of `NMinimize`, you'll see `u[5]`, `u[6]` therein.

Comment: Thanks, there was an error in the definition of `ui`. I modified my question.

Comment: Now try `Clear@point; Norm[point - {1, 2}]` and think about what's wrong here.

Comment: In my case , if `bez[...]` is evaluated  to a list of size 2, the argument of `Norm[bez[...],p[[i]]]` is ok I think.

Comment: `Norm` won't wait, `NMinimize` doesn't have `Hold*` `Attributes`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is, I think, to use the definition of a Bézier curve to define a `ParametricRegion` and then use `RegionDistance` to find out how well the curve approximates the points. Here's my suggestion. Define the points:

```
n = 5;
p = Table[{Cos[\[CurlyPhi]], Sin[\[CurlyPhi]]}, {\[CurlyPhi], 
    Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}, n], {Pi/2}]}];
```

Definition of the curve:

```
bezCurve[{pt : {_, _}}] := pt &;
bezCurve[ctrlPts_?MatrixQ] := bezCurve[ctrlPts] = 
   With[{b1 = bezCurve[Most[ctrlPts]], 
     b2 = bezCurve[Rest[ctrlPts]]}, (1 - #)*b1[#] + #*b2[#] &];
bezCurve[ctrlPts_?MatrixQ, t_] := Simplify[bezCurve[ctrlPts][t]];
```

Define the loss function to be minimized:

```
ClearAll[loss];
loss[pt : {__?NumericQ}] := loss[pt] = With[{
    regDist = RegionDistance[
      ParametricRegion[
       bezCurve[{p[[1]], pt, p[[-1]]}, t],
       {{t, 0, 1}}
       ]
      ]
    },
   Total@regDist[p]
  ]
```

Use `FindMinimum` to find the solution (will take a while):

```
FindMinimum[{loss[{x, y}], 
  0 < x < 3 && 0 < y < 3}, {{x, 0.937}, {y, 0.883}},
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print[{{x, y}, loss[{x, y}]}]
 ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll try to understand your code. I stumble first at the definitions `bezCurve[{pt : {_, _}}]` (?means: default argument is an empty list of length 2?) and  `loss[pt : {__?NumericQ}] `(?means: only numerical lists?) .

Comment: `bezCurve[{pt : {_, _}}]` means that it will match something of the form `bezCurve[{{x, y}}]` and then substitute `pt` on the r.h.s. with `{x, y}` (i.e., with the outer list stripped off). There is no default argument here; that would involve a second colon. The confusion is understandable, though, since the colon is a bit weird in Mathematica. You're correct about `loss[pt : {__?NumericQ}]`: it will only match things like `loss[{1.2, 3.5}]`. A slightly better pattern would've been `loss[pt : {_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ}]`, which will only match a list of exactly 2 numbers.

Comment: The loss function is really tricky!!! I'm still wondering why the use of the original `BezierFunction`  doesn't work inside `FindMinimum`

Comment: It's because of the order of the evaluation. That's why I have this `loss` function that won't evaluate symbolically. That ensures correct evaluation order when numerical values are substituted for `x` and `y`.

Answer (score 2):

There're 2 issues here:

1. The evaluation order should be properly controlled.
2. The argument of `BezierFunction` should be between $0$ and $1$, so we need to add constraints to `NMinimize`.

The following is the fixed code, I've also adjust `Method` option of `NMinimize` a bit to obtain better result:

```
SeedRandom[1];
n = 5; p = Table[{Cos[φ], Sin[φ]}, {φ, 
   Join[{0}, RandomReal[{0, Pi/2}, n], {Pi/2}]}];
ui = Table[u[i], {i, 2, Length[p] - 1}];

Clear@bez
bez[k : {{_?NumericQ, _?NumericQ} ..}] := BezierFunction[k]

Clear@norm;
norm[point_List, point2_] := Norm[point - point2]

NMinimize[{Sum[
    norm[bez[{p[[1]], {kx, ky}, p[[-1]]}][u[i]], p[[i]]], {i, 2, Length[p] - 1}], 
   0 <= # <= 1 & /@ ui}, Join[{kx, ky}, ui], Method -> "RandomSearch"] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{3.00299, {0.00958796, {kx -> 0.946537, ky -> 0.938663, u[2] -> 0.838486, 
   u[3] -> 0.0969485, u[4] -> 0.811814, u[5] -> 0.16807, u[6] -> 0.220674}}}
*)
```

Comment: Thanks for this nice solution. The two modifications of `BezierFunction` and `Norm` eliminate the problems I had. Furthermore the restrictions `0<u[i]<1` work much better than `0 u[1]<u[2]<...<1`